# Purpose of data-validation-rule and data-validation-default-value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have doubt in below code

```
<input id="textbox" value="2" data-validation-default-value="2" data-validation-rule="if(this.value!=this.attr('data-validation-default-value')return false;" />
```

Any one can explain purpose of this code?

Comment: can please explain ,why we have to use data-validation-default-value

Comment: Appears to be missing `)` at `if` condition? `javascript` string at `data-validation-rule` checks if input value is same as element `data-validation-default-value`

Comment: Any external script file reference needed for using data-validation in unobstrusive mode?